# AVFoundation documentation codes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion, avfoundation

I am reading Apple documentation regarding `AVFoundation` framework. I want a NSView in my Cocoa application to play video in my application. It's a tutorial video something similar to what apple provides in their application.

My question is, while reading this document...

[AVFoundation programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW2)

Most of the classes mentioned are related to iOS as an example...`PlayerView` extends from `UIView`.

Now, before I code I want to ask should if I am making application using same example code for Cocoa App should I read `UIView` as `NSView`? is that the solution?

I haven't tried as it's lots of code, I thought it's better to understand it before start coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific example you should be ok replacing UIView with NSView with possibly some minor changes, since it seems like a lot of the work is being done on the view's layer, which is a property that exists in AppKit as well as UIKit for NSView and UIIView respectively.

I am not sure what you overall goal is here, but as long as you are not intending to copy the doc line for line, you'll be ok; ie you might need to make small changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My final goal is to play a introduction video when my app starts :) , Thanks, let me test and I will get back!

Comment: No luck :(! I failed to play a video in it...Damn! I don't know why it's so hard...AVFoundation things are really easy on iOS :(

Comment: @TweetWithThisOwl_FollowMe I assume that you have sanity checked this by making sure that the vide is compatible? Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a simple QTMovieView loaded up with a video to play